# Should I use the Spring Framework jar files or Spring Batch jar files while creating a java email batch program?

Tags: java, spring, jar, spring-batch

I am trying to create a java email batch program that sends an email with an attachment each day to a specific email address, and I have to use Spring as the framework for this program.  It is not going to be a web application, but since I'm implementing Spring into this, how would I go about this?  I am totally new to Spring (and Java for that matter), but am unsure of which direction I need to go.  Which jar files do I need?  Spring Batch or Spring Framework?  Also, where can I download the jar files for Spring Framework?  The spring.io site won't let me download those jar files.

Comment: I'd suggest using Maven or Ivy for the dependency management, but if you want to jump just one hurdle at a time, then you can find Spring jars here: http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/

Answer (score 0):

I very strongly suggest you use a build tool that handles dependency management. Such tools are Ant+Ivy, Maven and Gradle. They will take care of downloading the appropriate jars based on your declaration of what dependencies you need and will take care of all the transitive dependencies.

One good way of getting started with Spring Batch is to follow [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) tutorial using either Maven or Gradle (the latter would probably be easier since you don't need to install it - the tutorial's code has a wrapper).

The tutorial uses Spring Boot which vastly simplifies Spring configuration (which is a serious benefit especially for someone who is new to Spring)

Answer (score 0):

As others already told you, I personally would not start any spring based project (means: any project) without maven! You have so much benefits from it, not only depencency management.

To start a spring app outside an application context:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  //any bean configurations here
}


//your entry class
static void main(String args[]) {
    //get a reference to the spring context. use this context throughout your app!
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(CacheConfig.class).get();

    //optain any beans from the context. inside these beans, you can use any spring feature you like, eg @Autowired
    ctx.getBean(YourBean.class).executeMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend starting with Spring Boot which will handle all of that for you.  As others have mentioned, pick a build tool (Maven or Gradle) and follow the guide we provide on building a batch application here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/.